# Sony Vaio laptop screen not working

Tags: display, sony-vaio

I have a Sony vaio VPCEH18FG. After shutting it down using the power button, when I try to turn it on it shows me grey screen and after some time turns off. What should I do next to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

### Display Driver Issue.

The Power Button in Windows (VAIO) puts the computer to sleep. When you press the power button again it wakes the computer, but in that process all the drivers load successfully except the Display Driver. This is why your screen is black (the illusion of grey is because of the back-light). Most of the times you will see a Blue Screen of Death indicating the display driver crashed.

**The solution:**

- Go to Control panel>Power Options> Choose what the Power buttons do> When I press the Power Button> On Battery, Plugged in: **Shut Down**.
- Go to Control panel>Power Options> Choose what the Power buttons do> When I press the Sleep Button> On Battery, Plugged in: **Shut Down**.
- Go to Control panel>Power Options> Choose what the Power buttons do> When I close the lid> On Battery, Plugged in: **Do nothing**.
- Go to Control panel>Power Options> Change plan settings> Put the computer to sleep> On Battery, Plugged in: **Never**.

**Important:** Don't put the computer to hibernate or to sleep.